# JSF Validation fails for no (obvious) reason

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete, view-scope

I have a couple of mandatory PrimeFaces 5.2 `<p:autoComplete>` components in my JSF 2.2 page tied to a `@ViewScoped` bean. The page consists of the following mandatory elements:

- Employee (p:autoComplete)
- Order (p:autoComplete)
- Location (p:autoComplete)
- WorkingTime (p:inputText)
- Description (p:inputTextArea)
- DaysOfBookkeeping (custom component for a multi date picker).

When I complete the form and submit the record immediately, everything works fine. When I leave the form alone for a couple of minutes before hitting the submit button, I get validation errors for "Order" and "Location", even though the values in the form are still present and the HTTP-POST is exactly the same as during the successful submit. In the HTTP-Post I can see, that the values for "Order" and "Location" are set, just like during the succesful HTTP-POST. I never get any validation errors for "Employee", even there's no difference between the three `p:autoComplete` elements.

```
javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=NewTimesheetForm%3AsH_submit&javax.faces.partial.execute
=%40all&javax.faces.partial.render=NewTimesheetForm%3Agrowl&NewTimesheetForm%3AsH_submit=NewTimesheetForm
%3AsH_submit&NewTimesheetForm=NewTimesheetForm&NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_employeeAutoComplete_input=Sebastian
+Lang&NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_employeeAutoComplete_hinput=df27af76-9937-4e28-bee8-66a000f0ce9c&NewTimesheetForm
%3AMain_dateArray_input=&NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_dateArray_datepicker=&NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_wspOrderAutoComplete_input
=Development+(Kolibri)&  NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_wspOrderAutoComplete_hinput=21c2259e-08bf-4a98-b718-8be67dba3b55&NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_locationAutoComplete_input=Wien&NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_locationAutoComplete_hinput
=15e41fee-ef98-4176-a118-032cef4e4c02&NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_workingTime=12&NewTimesheetForm%3AMain_description
=123&javax.faces.ViewState=15843050982783687%3A7588832336313498775
```

Any ideas what might be the reason for the validation errors?

- PrimeFaces 5.2
- Mojarra 2.2.10
- Wildfly 9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong `converter`. This is the right way to do it: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter